# Verb synonyms for 'come/spring to mind'

Tags: synonyms

What are some more formal synonyms in the form of a verb, preferably one word? thesarus.com produced ['strike'](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/come%20to%20mind?s=t), but it is transitive and sounds too grating. 'Arrive' sounds noncontextual.

Comment: *occur* ? among other possibilities.

Comment: Some metaphor; we don't have the vocabulary to talk about thinking. And you want an inchoative verb. Maybe there is one, if you pick the right metaphor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> occurs
>
> It *occurs* to me that 'occurs' is the word that you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

What about "I hit on an idea"?

Comment: +1 I can see myself saying that in some circumstances.   I will say that it is not really a "formal" synonym though - it's more of an idiom, I think?

Comment: No, I don't reckon it an idiom. Maybe it's less frequently used as "come to mind" and slightly less formal...

Answer (score -1):

Consider Materialize / Materialise or transpire.

The idea materialized in my mind whilst I was talking to a customer.

How can the average person hope to know what thoughts transpired in Einsteins brilliant mind.